# Log sharepoint security events to the windows event log

Tags: security, logging

Is it possible, through either a configuration setting or some minor conding, to make SharePoint log all security events to the Windows Event Log?

I'm primarily interested in events that deal with adding and removing memberships to groups.

I know I can use the audit log to log such events, but I was hoping it was possible to surface the same events in the event log as well.